# C++ Access violation reading location error

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I have template class MinMaxHeap and there two heap in it

```
    template <class T> class MinMaxHeap {
    public:
    Heap<T> minHeap;
    Heap<T> maxHeap;
    int Size;
    int capacity;

    template <class T>
MinMaxHeap<T>::MinMaxHeap(int capacity) {
    this->capacity = capacity;
    this->Size = 0;
    maxHeap = Heap<T>(capacity, false);
    minHeap = Heap<T>(capacity, true);
    maxHeap.otherHeap = &minHeap;
    minHeap.otherHeap = &maxHeap;
}
```

And there Heap class:

```
template <typename T> class Heap {

public:

    pair<T, int> *arr;
    int capacity;
    int size;
    Heap<T> *otherHeap;

    template <class T>
Heap<T>::Heap() {
}

template <class T>
Heap<T>::Heap(int capacity, bool isMin) {
    this->capacity = capacity;
    this->size = 0;
    arr = new pair<T, int>[this->capacity + 1];
    if (isMin) {
        arr[0] = pair<T, int>(NULL, 0);
    }
    else {
        arr[0] = pair<T, int>(NULL, 1);
    }
}
```

When I creating MinMaxHeap like this `MinMaxHeap<int> heap(20), MinMaxHeap<double> heap(20)` it works good, but when I trying to make `MinMaxHeap<String> heap(20)` I have an error:

> Exception thrown at 0x55B63E90 (ucrtbased.dll) in MinMaxHeap.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

After some debuging I saw that error occurs at these lines:

```
if (isMin) {
        arr[0] = pair<T, int>(NULL, 0);
    }
    else {
        arr[0] = pair<T, int>(NULL, 1);
    }
```

How to fix this problem ?

Comment: In addition to the correct answer below, note that you shouldn't use `NULL` anymore in modern code. Use `nullptr` if you need a null pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't create a `std::string` from a null pointer.

`NULL` is not a good choice for a default value of an arbitrary type – you should use `T`'s "own" default value, `T()`.

Answer (score -2):

NULL is a define in c, its like this:
       #define NULL 0

In my point of view, it can be implicitly casted to int, and double it is not gonna be a problem, but at the string case it cannot be casted to string.

I think you are only adding this variable to the array to know where is the end, why dont you use size for it? And a bool to know if it is min or max heap?